# Variable Password Requirements Help

Tags: password, security

Standford University recently [published](http://itservices.stanford.edu/service/accounts/passwords/quickguide) a quick guide to their password requirements:

[image]

While I quite like this method and this guide is great, I can't think of a nice way to concisely express this information inline to a user when they are entering a new password.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how you could communicate these requirements to a user based on what they have already typed? In particular, what would you display to the user if they had already typed in 5 all lowercase characters?

Comment: Why not just use a [password strength indicator](http://www.egrappler.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/password-strength-checker.jpg). It encourages people in real-time to use more complex passwords, but doesn't force the case. You can always have a `?` button to show user the full requirements such as this, but it just makes things more complicated really. Don't tell them what to do, *guide* them instead.

Comment: What I would like to know is how many passwords are "hacked" because of insufficient length ? Every time we heard about stolen passwords is due to a massive database hack so the length is not that useful

Comment: @Renaud I think you have a valid point, but I'd expand it to say "hacked" instead of "hacked because of ___". I think in general you're right, passwords simply aren't *hacked* anymore, they're just stolen in gigantic chunks.

Comment: The text in the bottom half of the ellipse at the top of the graphic seems pretty concise...

Comment: While brute-forcing character-by-character is defeated by long passwords, using common words to build a long passphrase still leaves users open to dictionary-based attacks.

Comment: xkcd [found 1949 *common* English words](http://preshing.com/20110811/xkcd-password-generator/). So with 4 words there is 1949 × 1948 × 1947 × 1946 = 1.438e+13 possibilities. The dictionary-based attack is useless. And this is only if the website forces the users to select 4 words, otherwise it's more complicated.

Comment: @JonW The problem with password strength indicators is that most people misunderstand what a strong password is. They tend to add more "odd" characters rather than increase the length - when length is often the "best" option.

Comment: @Renaud Many are hacked due to insufficient length. Those database hacks are (mostly) stealing encrypted passwords. Having shorter passwords means that those encrypted passwords are easier to crack. See http://www.lockdown.co.uk/?pg=combi for some out-of-date numbers.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure about their requirements and if they match yours, but Simple (simple.com) did a pretty great job with just the use of the word "passphrase". If you lead with that word and then gave a inline example like you've done at the bottom of your infographic, that might test well.

[image: passphrase too short]

[image: passphrase gets a B]

[image: a good passphrase]

This also might go against your requirements, but if what you want is the passphrase with the longer character count, I'd stay away from letting the user chose between lower characters with more multivariate character types and the longer passphrase. I'd just promote the behavior you want them to follow.

Answer (score 3):

I wish I could remember which site it was but I saw one registration form that did two things:

1. It had an estimate of how long it would take to crack the password.
2. It gave examples of how you could make it better

So you saw something like:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA35JU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>